# Using MathJax in text

Tags: plugins, latex, plugin-mathjax

I have installed a Mathjax plugin on my local wordpress installation, and the plugin works fine. However, I can't get it to show Latex in-text; it creates an own line for every latex formula. I end up with pages like this (this is an extreme example to get my point across better :)):

[image: Mathjax]

How can I make it work to show Latex in-text? I've tried multiple plugins and they all seem to have this issue, with no option to resolve this.

Comment: what kind of Latex commands do you use there ?

Comment: I just use $$ latex here $$. No matter what's between the dollar signs, the plugin will give it its own line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To create an inline formula in LaTeX we can use single dollar signs `$`:

```
This formula $x=y+z$ is inline.
```

To display math on its own line, we can use double dollar signs `$$`:

```
$$ a = b + c $$
```

Here is an example with [Simple Mathjax](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-mathjax/) installed:

[image: Editor]

This will be displayed like this:

[image: View]

Comment: I tried it and it worked. I cannot believe I missed that. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad to hear it worked for you ;-)